# Use .NET, Java, JGSoft RegEx flavor in PHP

Tags: java, php, .net, regex, pcre

As you may know, there are more than just one RegEx flavour: PCRE, one from Java, one from .NET ... etc, and all of them have a little different syntaxes and some have a feature more or less.

Now my question is, if somebody knows if it is possible to use, for example, the **flavour from .NET in PHP**.

I need this respectively I wonder if this is possible because I want to make a little Regular Expression checker for my website and there I want to give the user the choice you select his flavour...

Or is the only one solution to convert the patterns from one flavour to another manually?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to write your own php modules, which provide you functions like `net_match`, `java_match` and so on. These modules are more or less simple wrappers, which may do a system call to an external program written in the respective language. As i never wrote a php mod, i don't know, if you have to write it in a specific language.
I do also think, your webserver *must* be on a windows machine, as I have no idea of a unix port for .net [1](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

**EDIT**

[1](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) as Ghost pointed out, there IS a way to get .net running on UNIX machines, named [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: I think Windows might be the best approach, because you can get IIS to load the PHP run time, and with IKVM you can invoke Java libraries.  It would let you manage everything form one server (albeit a really complexly configured server)